# Python script: creating functioning loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I am currently trying to program a script for my school project. It is supposed to take one pixel from the camera feed and measure at that spot multiple times (for noise cancellation). The part of my code that I am not satisfied with currently looks like this:

```
canon.ScanXY(x,y)
img_1 = canon.FetchImage(0, 1 * 1)
canon.StopScan()

canon.ScanXY(x,y)
img_2 = canon.FetchImage(0, 1 * 1)
canon.StopScan()

...

canon.ScanXY(x,y)
img_xxx = canon.FetchImage(0, 1 * 1)
canon.StopScan()
```

The code above will return a string with name img_xxx where xxx stands for a specific number. I was wondering, if there is an easier way to do this. I was trying to loop the function, but was unable to do it so that I have different result from every iteration. And at the end I need to add all of those together in order to create one string from all that were generated before:

```
img_final = (img_1 + img_2 + img_3 + ... + img_xxx)
```

and finally to print a Picture out of the result, using

```
img = np.fromstring(img_final, dtype="uint8").reshape(8,8)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
ax.set_xticklabels((0,1))
x=ax.imshow(img,cmap="gray")
```

The code works, but if I want to change anything, it really takes a lot of time. So far I was working with 64 or less strings, but I want to refine the results, so I would need much more iterations. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"I was trying to loop the function, but was unable to do it so that I have different result from every iteration."* - Please show what you have tried doing and where the issues were. As is this is not a suitable question for SO

Comment: I think you're saying that `canon.FetchImage(0, 1 * 1)` returns a string containing the greyscale data at the (x, y) pixel? Is that correct? Is the data in that string a single byte? Also, I assume you're using Python 2, since in Python 3 you'd be using `bytes` objects instead of strings.

Comment: FetchImage function can store even bigger images, the `1 * 1` part stands for Picture size. However for our application we need just one pixel, and yes, I made a mistake, since I am using Python 3 it indeed uses `bytes` objects. And for the previous question, I tried to loop it with `for` function

Answer (score 0):

`img_final` is supposed to be the sum of a sequence of individual `img`'s.  The analogy to adding a sequence of integers read from the console would be:

```
final = int(input("First num: "))
for x in range(xxx-1):
    num = int(input("Next num: "))
    final += num
```